# Create Google Drive folder on behalf of users using Google Service account

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I created a service account and want to create folder on behalf of other users. I am using Google Drive API v3 (PHP).

I can create a folder under my service account, and try to transfer ownership to another user. But it can't work, and show unauthorized access.

In https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts, it mentions "Your application now has the authority to make API calls as users in your domain (to "impersonate" users). When you prepare to make authorized API calls, you specify the user to impersonate.". I am not sure how to do so.

Besides, I noted a function "$client->setSubject($email)", but I also can't make it work.

Please kindly advise and help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, and before you do anything else, make sure you understand that **Service Accounts can only impersonate users within their own Gsuite domain. They cannot impersonate xxx@gmail.com users**.

Assuming that you do indeed want to impersonate a Gsuite user, 
see https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts which says

> If you have delegated domain-wide access to the service account and
>   you want to impersonate a user account, specify the email address of
>   the user account using the method setSubject:
>
> $client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate);